# Python: Spliting rows element into new rows and copy other columns from excel file

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I have an Excel file. I want to split comma-separated row elements of "A-column" into new rows then save it into an Excel file.
How can I do this? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
  A-column           B-column

 A1, A2, A3     |    R1, R2
 B1, B2         |    D1, D2
 C1, C2, C3     |    D3
```

Output:

```
  A-column           B-column
  A1             |    R1, R2
  A2             |    R1, R2
  A3             |    R1, R2
  B1             |    D1, D2
  B2             |    D1, D2
  C1             |    D3
  C2             |    D3 
  C3             |    D3





import pandas as pd
import numpy as np`
  

data = pd.read_excel (r'test.xlsx'))
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['A', 'B'])
pd.concat([Series(row['B'], row['A'].split(','))              
for _, row in df.iterrows()]).reset_index()            
print(df)
```

Comment: Can you be more spesific? You may want to look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: Is the excel file storing values as csv data? Will the file have values as shown above when read by python?

Comment: it is xlsx data.